# What happened to the CustomDistribution() function in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have been using the CustomDistribution() function in AnyLogic to programmatically draw random values from a tableFunction. The code is used to validate that my tableFunction works. It draws a large number of samples from the TableFunction and stores them into a csv file.

```
String data="";
Random r=new Random(1);
CustomDistribution n=new CustomDistribution(tableFunction,r);
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    data+=n.get()+"\n";
}
try{
    Files.write(Paths.get("files.csv"), data.getBytes());
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run the code inside AnyLogic I get an error message that the CustomDistribution() function does not exist. Searching the AnyLogic Help and the internet did not help in finding a solution.

Comment: Is [this the Documentation](https://anylogic.help/advanced/functions/custom-distribution.html) for the feature you are looking for? Is createCustomDistribution() the function you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the constructors that [AnyLogic API](https://anylogic.help/advanced/functions/custom-distribution.html#creating-a-custom-distribution-programmatically) gives you, i.e. either `CustomDistributionDiscrete`, `CustomDistributionContinuous` or `CustomDistributionOptions`.

Always use code-complete and the API help to understand what you can and cannot do :)

Comment: I had a look at the AnyLogic API Javadoc, but from the description I cannot work out what I have to do to construct the custom distribution. Perhaps you can provide a code example? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on which you choose, for example `new CustomDistributionDiscrete( new double[]{1,2,3,4})`